# Getting data from a list into a datagridview

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio, datagridview, event-driven

I'm creating a event-driven shopping cart and as a result I'm getting it to display in a datagridview but it's first of all storing the information in a list and from that list it's going to the datagridview when I click the Checkout Button.

What then happens is the columns and rows are generated but then it also displays the rows but the data isn't visible only the rows a columns.

this is what's it's like at the moment.

```
//defines the list and links to the where the product information is and when a product is added to the cart.
public static List<BulkPurchase> cart = new List<BulkPurchase>();
```

```
private void btnCheckout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //makes the checkout visible
            pnlMain.Visible = false;
            //makes the products not visible
            pnlCheckout.Visible = true;

//just shows me that items have been added to the list
            foreach (var item in cart)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.getName());
                Console.WriteLine(item.getPrice());
            }
            //inputs the cart to the datagridview
            dataGridView1.DataSource = cart;
        }
```

BulkPurchase class

```
    public class BulkPurchase : Product
    {
        private int quantity;
        
        public BulkPurchase(string prodName, float prodPrice, int prodQuantity)
            : base(prodName, prodPrice)
        {
            this.quantity = prodQuantity;
        }
    }
```

Product Class

```
    public class Product
    {
        private string name;
        private float price;

        //the constructor for a product
        public Product (string prodName, float prodPrice)
        {
            this.name = prodName;
            this.price = prodPrice;
        }

        //accessing the private variable of name
        public string getName() => name;

        //accessing the private variable of price 
        public float getPrice() => price;        
    }
```

[When I add three items to the list this is the outcome of the datagridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r5mh.jpg)

I'm completely stumped in how to solve this issue and all the Googling and YouTube doesn't sadly help.

Comment: You need to show what `BulkPurchase` look like.  Dollars to Donuts you have fields not properties

Comment: Okay  cool thanks for that @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp I've added the other two classes if that helps.

Comment: I think first thing you need to do is to switch to properties and not use `get` and `set` methods... Public properties will be used to retrieve the data for display purpose when the collection is bound to the controls like GridView, ListView, ComboBox etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you mean.
The first thing you need to do is to define a public product name property, a public price property, and a public quantity property.
The properties are readable and writable properties.
In this way, the control can access those private fields outside the class.

My modification is as follows:

**//Manually add examples directly to the list in the demo**

```cs
//Write three data as an example
           cart.Add(new BulkPurchase("apple",10,1));
           cart.Add(new BulkPurchase("banana", 20, 1));
           cart.Add(new BulkPurchase("orange", 10, 1));
```

**//Product**

```cs
public class Product {
            private string name;
            private float price;

            public string ProductName {
                get {
                    return name;
                }
                set {
                    name = value;
                }
            }    
            public float Price {
                get {
                    return price;
                }
                set {
                    price = value;
                }
            }
```

**//BulkPurchase**

```cs
public class BulkPurchase : Product {
            private int quantity;

            public BulkPurchase(string prodName, float prodPrice, int prodQuantity)
                : base(prodName, prodPrice) {
                Quantity = prodQuantity;
            }
           public int Quantity {
                get {
                    return quantity;
                }
                set {
                    quantity = value;
                }
            }
        }
```

**//Display the total amount.**

```cs
float TotalPrice = 0;
foreach (var item in cart) {
    TotalPrice += (item.Price*item.Quantity);
}
pnlCheckout.Text = $"Total $ {TotalPrice}";
```

**//Put quantity in the third column.**

```cs
dataGridView1.DataSource = cart;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DisplayIndex = 2;
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you very much that helped heaps and it made me understand it thoroughly.